# LTspice .TRAN UIC simulations with initial conditions as .IC directives

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, simulation, spice, power-up-conditions

Starting from this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541707/ltspice-transient-simulation-of-lc-circuit) a doubt arises about the use of (global) .IC directives for 'branch currents' in LTspice (or maybe just SPICE)

Consider the .TRAN card with UIC flag. From some test done it seems to me possibly .IC directives set for inductor currents (e.g. .IC I(L1)=10) are actually not employed as initial conditions.

Is anyone aware of this? Thanks

[image]

---

---

Edit: Based on the comments received I add another screenshot for the simulation of the same circuit this time with the L1 inductor initial current set at device level (per-instance)

[image]

As you can see the result is different. This time it seems device-level condition for I(L1) is actually taken in in account. Thus for the .TRAN simulation with UIC flag it seems the global .IC directive for 'node voltages' *alone* is actually taken in account (to work out the voltage initial conditions for capacitors)

My question was to confirm this behavior. Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit in the discrepancy you're trying to point out?  It's not self-evident.

Comment: Sure, I'm going to edit the question

Comment: If you set `ic=-10` in the inductor, you'll get the oscillations, but at twice the value. Setting it to zero creates identical outputs. Changing the sign in the `.IC` card doesn't seem to change the response. This needs more investigation.

Comment: Have you some other info/comment about it ?